# Let $f\in C[-1,1]$ show that if $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)p(x^2)dx=0$ for all polynomials $p$ then $f$ is odd.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f\in C[-1,1]$ show that if $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)p(x^2)dx=0$ for all polynomials $p$ then $f$ is odd.

I found a solution and I would like to know if it is correct, and if there are better solutions.

First Solution:

Consider $L^2[-1,1]$ we know that is has an orthogonal decomposition into even and odd functions. By stone Weierstrass even polynomials are dense in $L^2[0,1]$ and so must be dense in even functions of $L^2[-1,1]$. Thus the assumption tells us that $f$ is orthogonal do a dense set of even functions. So it is orthogonal to all even function. Thus it must be inside the orthogonal complement, i.e an odd function.

Comment: There is a gap in your argument. Where does $p(x^{2})$ come into your argument?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy "Thus the assumption tells us that f is orthogonal do a dense set of (the space of) even functions"

Comment: So you have to prove that functions of the form $p(x^{2})$ are dense in the set of even functions to complete your argument.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That follows from the fact that even polynomials are dense in $L^2[0,1]$  as I said in my post. Is that not true?

Comment: No, it does not. Even polynomials are not dense in $L^{2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy They are in $L^2[0,1]$. You apply stone Weierstrass to even polynomials to show they are dense in continuous functions in $C[0,1]$. Thus they are dense in $L^2[0,1]$

Comment: Seems like you could maybe prove it directly by integrating against polynomials of the form $(x^2)^n(1-x^2)^n$ or something like that (with some scaling to hit different values).